# How to know if a user is logged in UNIX

Tags: unix

I am trying to update a UNIX shell script to run only if the user is NOT logged into their UNIX account. I have considered using 
     finger

Then look for the text "On since"...

However I have found that when I finger a particular user account that I just logged into via Putty, that user supposedly "Never logged in."

How would someone see if the user is physically logged into the UNIX system??

Thank you,

Comment: What version of Unix are you running?

Comment: Sorry Solaris 10.  I found the "w" command to provide useful information about users.  Is this a reliable command for determining current login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"who -a" ... ? Shows also the associated terminal to a connected user.

Comment: who -a shows several instance of the user as well as other logins. How can I tell which or if one of these is current? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, if you have the login of the user you want to check, run a simple ps -u <login> | wc -l, if the output equals 1, it means he has no processes launched (i.e he is not connected), otherwise he is.

Answer (score 2):

Use `who`.  http://linux.die.net/man/1/who

Comment: unfortunately, I need to be able to do this remotely. the w command seems to allow me to find out about other users where who does not.

Answer (score 1):

The `last` command may be helpful, which tells the history of when someone has logged in and how they got there.  EG, you can tell if it's from a remote login (ssh) or from a terminal (a real tty), etc.

Comment: last command gives a lot more than what I need.  I am looking to see if a user is logged in before executing another script. the last command gives entire activity listing.

Comment: @iowatiger08, Use `last -n 1 <username>` to limit to the last login.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could easily write your own Perl / php / Python script to directly check the Utmp logs, as to whether a user is currently logged in e.g.

Python: **isLoggedIn.py** [userid]

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from pyutmp import UtmpFile
import sys

for utmp in UtmpFile():
    # utmp is a Utmp object
    if utmp.ut_user_process:
        if utmp.ut_user in sys.argv:
            print "User: %s  is logged in\n" % (utmp.ut_user)
            sys.exit(0)
print "Not logged in\n"
sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: I get `ImportError: No module named pyutmp` when run your script